# Excel VLookup based on two variables across 3 sheets

Tags: excel

I am trying to sum the totals of data stored in 3 sheets based on 2 variables into a summary sheet (ie. a forth sheet).

I want to match both the place name and the week number for each place on the summary sheet.

On the Summary table we have at the top the week number we want to use. A list of places in column A and the number of visits in column B.

THis formula worked.

```
=SUMIFS(ND!$V$3:$V$4000,ND!$F$3:$F$4000,TEST!$A$1,ND!$B$3:$B$4000,TEST!A3)
```

In column B of the summary sheet for each row. However it only looks up data from one sheet not all 3. I tried this but it causes an error:

```
=SUMIFS(AND(ND!$V$3:$V$4000,GK!$V$3:$V$4000,TW!$W$3:$W$4000),AND(ND!$F$3:$F$4000,GK!$F$3:$F$4000,TW!$F$3:$F$4000),TEST!$A$1,AND(ND!$B$3:$B$4000,GK!$B$3:$B$4000,TW!$B$3:$B$4000),TEST!A3)
```

How do we get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you just use the formula

```
=SUMIFS(ND!$V$3:$V$4000,ND!$F$3:$F$4000,TEST!$A$1,ND!$B$3:$B$4000,TEST!A3)
```

3 times like

```
=SUMIFS(ND!$V$3:$V$4000,ND!$F$3:$F$4000,TEST!$A$1,ND!$B$3:$B$4000,TEST!A3)+SUMIFS(GK!$V$3:$V$4000,GK!$F$3:$F$4000,TEST!$A$1,GK!$B$3:$B$4000,TEST!A3)+SUMIFS(GW!$V$3:$V$4000,GW!$F$3:$F$4000,TEST!$A$1,GW!$B$3:$B$4000,TEST!A3)
```

Comment: How could I not think of that... W